# Durable Topic Subscription in .Net

Tags: c#

I am looking at identifying any thing Open Source which I can use for Durable Topic Subscription in C#. If any body is aware, please guide me to the appropriate resource. I am not able to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy as far as I know, there are not many open source ones. The one that you might be interested is an offering from Neudesic. Apart from that you might be intrested in Biztalk 2009.

Thats about it. BTW, do go through the JMS Specification and it would really help.